# Invalid API key error from GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY when pulling as repository secret

Tags: testing, github-actions

We are currently using GitGuardian to scan our keys in GitHub repository. Upon testing, we encountered issues on sample files because there are keys exposed on the repository. We wanted to use the feature that would allow us to use "ignore specific paths" on GitHub actions since the sample files are publicly available and there would be no issues if it is included in the repository. Using the feature, we encountered issues on the created GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY with an “Invalid API key” error. Here is an example of the created yaml file for the GitHub actions

```
   env:
     GITHUB_PUSH_BEFORE_SHA: ${{ github.event.before }}
     GITHUB_PUSH_BASE_SHA: ${{ github.event.base }}
     GITHUB_PULL_BASE_SHA: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}
     GITHUB_DEFAULT_BRANCH: ${{ github.event.repository.default_branch }}
     GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY }}
```

A specific API key was tested locally and it worked. It was put into the variable GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY. We assume that it might have been some issue with the gg-shield github actions or something.

I am using actions/checkout@v3.5.1 , GitGuardian/ggshield-action@v1.15.0

Answer (score 0):

> A specific API key was tested locally and it worked. It was put into the **variable** GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY

GitHub `Secrets` and `Variables` are two different concepts.

If you want to use variables in GitHub Actions, you need to use `${{ vars.GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY }}`.